# Question concerning computing $\pi_1(\mathbb R^{3}-B)$ in Alexander Horned Sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I was studying an example of the Alexander Horned Sphere on page 171 of Allen Hatcher's book. The example computes the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbb R^{3}-B)$ of the complement of the sphere in $\mathbb R^{3}$, which I found that very difficult to understand. Could anyone please suggest me some materials other than Allen Hatcher's to understand that example?

Comment: Rolfsen's book Knots and Links has a sequence of exercises that show $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3 - B)$ isn't finitely generated. I'm not sure it's all that different from Hatcher's description though.

Comment: [Crossposted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659209/39599). Please don't do that.

Comment: Sorry. I will delete the post on stackexchange.